# How to display data in ( materialBetterSpinner ) different from data included in source

Tags: android

I Use (materialBetterSpinner) in my app to select the data that I will save in the database ..
Now I have two data in materialBetterSpinner to choose from it. The problem now I store  number in materialBetterSpinner as (String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"1", "0"};) because I need to save a number in my databases but users now also see a number .. I don't  want users see numbers.. I need make  users see and select words .. but in my code that word Equal a number.

For example now I have this (String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"1", "0"};) but I need users see this like that (String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"test1", "test2"};)
 so if user select  test1  he actually chose the number 1 like that.

What user see now ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK59l.png)

what I want user see ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmyaW.png)

If anyone know the solution help me ..

My code ..

```
String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"1", "0"};
MaterialBetterSpinner materialBetterSpinner;
```

```
  materialBetterSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.material_spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptermatr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewTopic.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SPINNER_DATA);
        materialBetterSpinner.setAdapter(adaptermatr);
```

```
    private void upload() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                params.put("size", materialBetterSpinner.getEditableText().toString().trim());



                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = (RequestQueue) Volley.newRequestQueue(AddNewTopic.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call by it's position

```
String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"1", "0"}; // then array position will be [0,1]

String[] SECOND_ARRAY = {"test1", "test2"}; // then array position will be [0,1]

String SelectedValue;

 materialBetterSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.material_spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptermatr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewTopic.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SPINNER_DATA);
        materialBetterSpinner.setAdapter(adaptermatr);
```

so when user click the spinner item call out the postion of SECOND_ARRAY

```
 materialBetterSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),SECOND_ARRAY[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                       SelectedValue = SECOND_ARRAY[position];
                    }
                });
```

So as you mentioned if you click the `1` in the spinner it will toast as `test1`

Comment: Ok it's work like that but just one problem how I will insert that value now ? I was do that by ( params.put("size", materialBetterSpinner.getEditableText().toString().trim());)

Comment: why don't you store it in a String variable?... Like `String value = SECOND_ARRAY[position];`

Comment: I try like that        params.put("size", value.toString()); but not work

Comment: did you declared `String` globaly?

Comment: I apologize I'm new developer .. Yes it works now Thank you brother

Comment: Don't worry about being new developer everything is learned from mistakes... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use to show (String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"test1", "test2"};)
And use position to store in database/ use to store on the basis of selected item

```
materialBetterSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String spinner_value= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),spinner_value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: So user will be see ((String[] SPINNER_DATA = {"test1", "test2"};) ) ok that line is clear.. but in your code from where I will get the number ?I apologize, but I am a new developer with little experience..

Comment: you can get the selected item by using ```adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()``` and you can set the number on the basis of selected item

Comment: but like that I will get test1", or "test2 and that what user select but I need insert to db just number

Comment: you want to store 1 instead of test1 and 0 instead of test 2 is that correct, If correct the check the selected item if it's test1 then store 1 if not then store 0. This is what I understand

Comment: Yes, my brother is like that

Comment: Thank you my brother it is working now .. and I apologize for not understanding well

Comment: you're welcome. It's great to hear that you got your answer